# Can there be a voltage spike from ULN2803 to MCP23017?

Tags: raspberry-pi, uln2803

I would like to ensure I have designed my circuit to operate safely. I am trying to control a 12V electric lock using Raspberry Pi.
I have connected my SCL and SDA to MCP23017 and the output of MCP23017 to ULN2803. I have connected +12V source power to ULN2803 COM and + of the electronic lock, while -12V to ULN2803's ground.

- Do I need any resister to have my circuit operate safely without current spikes going back to MCP or Raspberry Pi?
- Is it a problem to connect all the grounds back to Raspberry including -12V?

I am using 10K resister for MCP'reset.

Comment: "*... while -12V to ULN2803's ground.*" I think you mean you have connected 0 V to ULN2803's ground. Can you edit to fix that? Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider your electric lock being most likely a coil. When you switch off your coil, you will have a voltage spike at the coil leads or anything connected to it.

To solve this problem, the common solution is to place a [fly-back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) diode at the coil so that the voltage has somewhere to go.

The good thing is that the ULN2803 directly integrates this diode for each pin and they are all connected to the COM pin.

[image]
 Make sure the COM is connected to the + of the supply and coil, as you mentioned it should be fine.

---

Concerning connecting the ground altogether, it is probably not fine to connect -12VDC to the ground as it would short the power supply. Are you sure it is actually -12VDC? if so you probably don't need it at all and just connect the +12VDC and GND.

Comment: thanks @Damien for replying. the adapter I am using is similar to this: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61hxi-g%2BINL._AC_SL1200_.jpg. as you can see it shows it have positive and negative. now my concern is that whether I can connect the negative to the raspberry pi ground? any difference between negative and ground?

Comment: This is an isolated supply so it is floating, you can connect the ground to raspberry without any worries. (There is no -12VDC, just GND and +12VDC) @AbdulkarimKanaan

Comment: thank you for your help. what's in case the adapter has a safty ground (non-floating) like this: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71R-GzfSGOL._SX425_.jpg would be still safe to use? and in what case do I need to worry about grounding?

Comment: Another question please, I have already tested the circuit and it is working fine. However, I have observed something werid that when I try to connect +12V while the circuit is in operation (python script is running), the led connected to the output of MCP as a signal indicator will stop working sometimes until I restart (stop and run) the script again. What is happening? Is there any problem I should take care of?